# Using the auth0 /oauth/token endpoint from python

Tags: python, python-requests, auth0

I'm trying to figure out how Auth0 works. So far I'm not lucky. What I am trying to achieve is simple: POST to the oauth/token endpoint and receive a token in return. With curl this is no problem. I can curl --request POST [...] and receive a token just fine. When I try to do this using python and pythons requests module I'm getting an error stating that I'm not authorized. The data is exactly the same, I double checked. Here's my python code:

```
import json, requests

endpoint = 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': 'myuser',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'audience': '',
    'scope': 'read:sample',
    'client_id': 'myclientid',
    'client_secret': 'myclientsecret'
},
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url=endpoint, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print("STATUS: ", response.status_code)
print("Response: ", response.json())
```

Working Curl request:

```
curl --request POST \\
  --url 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token' \\
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \\
  --data '{"grant_type":"password","username": "myuser","password": "mypassword","audience": "", "scope": "read:sample", "client_id": "myclientid", "client_secret": "myclientsecret"}'
```

I also tried setting the user agent in my python code to "curl/7.51.0", but that also did not work :D

I'm happy with any pointer!

EDIT:

I shamefully have to admit that I did not use the same username afterall. That didn't change the fact though that I could not authorize myself with the python code. The SDK as suggested by @cricket_007 works fine. I find this a little bit weird but well.

Comment: Can you please show the full curl request?

Comment: I added the curl request.

Comment: The header should be `Content-Type`, but I don't know if that really matters

Comment: Not clear why you're using requests anyway. Auth0 has a Python SDK https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python/blob/master/auth0/v3/authentication/get_token.py

Comment: I know the SDK exists, but it's not without faults itself and since I only need the token, I thought an api call will be sufficient. I will look into the SDK again though, thanks!
Still I would like to know why I can't simply call the endpoint from a python file...

Comment: The class I linked to does get the token, and it uses requests internally

Comment: Yes, I tried it with the SDK and it works fine! Thank you for taking your time to look into this!

Comment: If the HTTP response says you are unauthorized, then most likely the `client_id`/`client_secret` pair is not correct (is what you use in a token request to authorize the client). Sorry to state the obvious, but could you double-check it?

Comment: Thanks for the response @NicoSabena. I'm certain they were the same as in my curl request. Anyways, I'm going with the SDK for now, it works and I'm happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually a simple error in your usage of `requests.post()`

**url** is not a key word argument:

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

should work here...

Comment: Thanks for your resonse!

The way I posted it here is just a variant of all the different things I tried. In the beginning I had it exactly like you wrote it... didn't make a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

I now the question was a long time ago but this is simply an issue with `data=` it should be replaced with `json=`

The request becomes:

```py
response = requests.post(endpoint, json=data, headers=headers)
```

And you save a `json.dumps`.